# Recurring Decimal number loss

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am working on a project where we have to get the value by converting one unit to another. For e.g KG to CAR, CAR to CASE.

So, we usually figure out a conversion factor first and then use it to multiply.

For example,

10 Kg = 3 CAR

So, 1 KG = 0.3 CAR and 1 CAR = 3.333 KG

The problem is that when such recurring decimal like that one in above ( 3.3333...) occurs and we use it for calculation we get a difference in the value and the business is calculating. They would use 0.3 to multiply.

I would like to know if there is an algorithm which can tell us which number exactly we should be multiplying or dividing so that we retain the maximum amount of information.

30 * 0.3 = 9
While, 30/3.333 = 9.0009
30/3.33 = 9.0090

This doesn't show the issue properly, but for larger number it's quite big.
 So, we should always want to get complete value such as 9 in the above example.

Can anyone here share any algorithm so as to when to multiply and when to divide?

Tl:dr ; Any algorithm to identify recurring number.

Comment: Sorry, this MO website is for questions of math research.